# Is it possible to add tooltip on material ui chip component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The requirement is I have label eg: Color and value eg: orange.
So I want to show label as tooltip and value as chip. Is it possible to do with chip? if not is there any other way that I can achieve this.

I am using material-ui version v0.18.7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to get a basic tooltip is to use the `title` attribute:

```
<Chip title="Color">
  Orange
</Chip>
```

If you want a more powerful tooltip, you can use the [`Tooltip` component](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tooltips/) added material-ui v1. That will let you have more control over the placement and appearance of the tooltip.

Comment: Ok I will test this and let you know possibly tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry! I got another critical issue so I got diverted. Yes I verified now and its working absolutely fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution to add tooltip on mui chip component for latest mui versions:

```
   <Tooltip title='Color'>
     <Chip
      label='Orange'
     />
    </Tooltip>
```